# Webpack config error with html-webpack-plugin for creating index.html

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying some POC with webpack for bundling project JS files.

I want to create an index.html file under output dist folder via webpack. For this purpose as per [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#setting-up-htmlwebpackplugin), installed  "html-web-plugin" via npm as :

```
npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin
```

It updates in package.json file as below:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0"
  }
```

Used this plugin in webpack.config.js as per [documentation of webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#setting-up-htmlwebpackplugin):

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
```

And inside config object:

```
plugins: [
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
    title: 'Output Management'
 )
],
```

To run npm scripts, used below code in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
  "devNoServer": "webpack --d --watch",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
  "build": "webpack -p",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

On running **npm run dev** OR **npm run build** command, getting **below error** which seems related to html-web-plugin:

```
/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:373
    throw e;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'make' of undefined
    at PersistentChildCompilerSingletonPlugin.apply (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/cached-child-compiler.js:182:20)
    at new CachedChildCompilation (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/cached-child-compiler.js:68:44)
    at HtmlWebpackPlugin.apply (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:92:33)
    at Compiler.apply (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375:16)
    at webpack (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:33:19)
    at startDevServer (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:367:16)
    at /<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:358:5
    at /<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/portfinder/lib/portfinder.js:196:16
    at /<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at replenish (/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1006:25)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-sample-broken@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-sample-broken@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /<USER_DIR>/.npm/_logs/2020-06-17T14_50_38_388Z-debug.log
```

**Without** using "html-webpack-plugin", npm run dev OR npm run build command works fine and create bundle.js in dist folder.

Is there something I'm doing wrong for using "html-webpack-plugin"?? I'm unable to find this error and it's fix anywhere.

Any input/ solutions will be really helpful.

Comment: You can take a look at line 182 of `node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/cached-child-compiler.js` to see what is this `make` and then you can run it like `npm run serve --inspect-brk` to initiate a debug session and eventually put a breakpoint at the above mentioned line to further investigate the issue.

Comment: Did you use webpack 4?

Answer (score 3):

Ok after hours of looking here and there, reading loads of documentation.This worked for me.
I was using this **"html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0"**
So I reverted back to using **html-webpack-plugin@2.24.1** and the make command worked.
Dont know for sure but could be version's issue.

Comment: Also ran into that issue with v5.3.1. Instead I looked up the latest v2 by running `npm view html-webpack-plugin@* version`, saw 2.30.1 was the latest for that major version, then ran `npm i html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1 --save-dev --save-exact`